# Is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ , where $f(x)=-1, (x\epsilon Q) , f(x)=1, (x\epsilon Q^c)$ an improper integral?

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ , where $f(x)=-1, (x\epsilon Q) ,  f(x)=1, (x\epsilon Q^c)$  an improper integral ?

For improper integral, there must either be a point of infinite discontinuity or limits of the integral as infinity. Here the limits is infinity but if I calculate limit of $f(x)$ as x tends to infinity, then it is finite I think, as the function assumes fixed points in the whole real line.
But I am really confused about this integral and how to write it while integrating. Any clarification will be highly helpful.

Thanking in advance.

Comment: This function is not Riemann integrable over any interval.

Comment: Yes, that I can prove by showing that upper and lower Riemann integrals for this function is different. But what about it being an improper integral or a proper integral ?

Comment: @Esha I'd say no for the reason Kavi said, but under some conditions I may also say yes.

Comment: @Gae.S. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I may say yes if I happen to be a subordinate of a person who is particularly adamant in calling "improper integral" the class of symbols in the form $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ for some function $f$ and extended real numbers $a,b$.

Comment: @Gae. S. So is it improper or proper? I am really very confused.